# Hard in Javascript interview

Tags: javascript, encoding, character, special-characters

Everybody.

Several days ago an Interviewer asked me a question.
And I couldn't answer it. May be at this site exists some guru JS. =)

**We have just one string**: `VARNAME[byte][byte][byte][byte]`   where `[byte]` is place for  one char.

**Question**: How write JS correct, if  ***pair*** of [byte][byte] in ***HEX MUST BE NOT MORE*** than 1000 in decimal?

**I tried following** :

1) `VARNAME[20][3D][09][30]`    it is equal

2) `VARNAME<space>=1<space>`    and it is correct JS CODE  BUT!

3) `0x203D =  8253` in decimal not correct must be <=1000
    `0x0120 = 2352` not correct must be <=1000!

I tried replacing 20 on 09, then:

`0x093d = 2365` it is more good, but more than 1000 =(

**How i can make it? Interviewer says that it is possible because char can be any**( i mean

`varname;<space><space><space>` and etc), but he can not say me an answer.

Who can make it guys?

Comment: What a silly interview question. Let me get this straight: the interviewer is asking you to provide four bytes to follow a variable name, and the byte values cannot be more than 1000 in aggregate?

Comment: This is a sucky interview question.

Comment: Yes, maybe you right. But He say that it is just for interesting and it is not necessarily. He said that it is hard question, for people who know JS

Comment: Given that 1000 is 0x3e8, this means that you can only use NUL, SOH, STX and ETX control characters in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as described has no answer.

The lowest code point that can appear in an expression context after a variable references is `\u0009` which, as you point out, will result in a value greater than 1000 (>= 2304). The ECMAScript 5 specification requires JavaScript environment to generate an early error when an invalid character is encountered. The only characters legal here are a identifier continuation character or a *InputElementDiv* which is either *Whitespace*, *LineTerminator*, *Comment*, *Token*, and *DivPunctuator*, none of which allow code points in the range `\u0000`-`\u0003` which would be required for the question to have an answer.

There are some environments that terminate parsing when a `\u0000` is encountered (the C end-of-string character) but those do not conform ES5 in this respect.

The statement that JavaScript allows any character in this position is simply wrong.

This all changes if VARNAME is in a string or a regular expression, however, which can both take character in the range `\u0000`-`\u0003`. If this is the trick the interviewer is looking for I can only say that was an unfair question.

Remember, in an interview, you are interviewing the company as much, or more, than the company is interviewing you. I would have serious reservations about joining a company that considers such a question a valid question to use in an interview.

Comment: Chuckj, Thank you very much, you are really great!you are guru!)))